# How translation a matrix(4x4) in Eigen?

Tags: c++, matrix, translation, eigen

How translation a matrix(4x4) in Eigen?

```
//identity matrix 4x4
/*type=*/Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 4> /*name=*/result = Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 4>::Identity();

//translation vector
// 3.0f
// 4.0f
// 5.0f
Translation<float, 3> trans(3.0f, 4.0f, 5.0f);
```

ie, I have matrix:

1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0
0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0
0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0

And I want get this:
1.0   0.0   0.0   **3.0**
0.0   1.0   0.0   **4.0**
0.0   0.0   1.0   **5.0**
0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0

Right? How I can do this?

I can do this:

```
result(0, 3) = 3.0f;
result(1, 3) = 4.0f;
result(2, 3) = 5.0f;
```

But it's not elegant. =) What you advice?

Comment: If you're not happy with writing three lines of code to perform a translation, then my advise would be to write a function to perform that translation and then call that function wherever you need to do the translation. This is normal elegant programming in any language.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like this:

```
Affine3f transform(Translation3f(1,2,3));
Matrix4f matrix = transform.matrix();
```

[Here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialGeometry.html) is the doc with more details.

Answer (score 8):

Some alternative to catscradle answer:

```
Matrix4f mat = Matrix4f::Identity();
mat.col(3).head<3>() << 1, 2, 3;
```

or

```
mat.col(3).head<3>() = translation_vector;
```

or

```
Matrix4f mat;
mat << Matrix3f::Identity, Vector3f(1, 2, 3),
       0, 0, 0,            1;
```

or

```
Affine3f a;
a.translation() = translation_vector;
Matrix4f mat = a.matrix();
```